# After a while the computer enters hybernate, how to disable?

Tags: windows-7, power-management

If I manually set the computer to sleep or just leave it alone, by the morning it appears to be switched off, in hybernate mode. This is very annoying because the computer is notebook and I have to remove monitor from top of it to switch on each time. I want the computer be in sleep so I could awake it from the keyboard.

In the power settings I only set up it to enter sleep after 1 hour, and there is no setting to enter hybernate. I wonder how to make it not to enter hybernate from sleep at all?

Comment: Did you even google for "Activating/Deactivating Hibernate"?

Comment: @daraos I do not want to deactivate hybernate, if I hybernate manually.

Comment: You didn't say that you want to put it into hibernation mode manually. You said that you want to put it into sleep mode without it switching to hibernation. Sleep mode is not the same as hibernation mode.

Comment: @daraos after I put it in sleep mode after a while it enters hybernation. I do not want it.

Comment: I don't see why disabling hibernate is no option for you. If you want to put it into hibernation mode manually, you enable it again. But it will keep the PC from hibernation when it's sleeping.

Comment: this link mentions methods. enabling , disabling, preventing it from hibernating automatically. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/819-hibernate-enable-disable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open **Power Options** by clicking the Start button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **System and Maintenance**, and then clicking **Power Options**.
2. On the **Select a power plan** page, click **Change plan settings** under the selected plan.
3. On the Change settings for the plan page, click **Change advanced power settings**.
4. On the **Advanced settings** tab, expand **Sleep**, expand **Hibernate** after, and then do one of the following:

   - If you are using a mobile PC, click On battery or Plugged in (or both), click the arrow, and then type Never.
5. Click **OK**, and then click **Save changes**.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/sleep-goes-to-hibernate-after-several-hours/a4759d26-5a8f-407f-ba1c-ccac6c43e101)

Comment: Thank you! Except that it did not accept "Never" and I had to guess the word on a non-English version of Windows :-)